# correctly locate image src (giving image a new src)

Tags: javascript, html

Currently i am trying to change an image on click to another image. I have managed to do so with the following code: (working)

```
 <img id="inv1imgid" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a2/X_mark.svg/525px-X_mark.svg.png" onclick="switchImage(this)" width="36" height="36" />
    var preselected = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a2/X_mark.svg/525px-X_mark.svg.png";
var selected = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/31/14/37/check-mark-1292787_960_720.png";

var switchImage = function(image) {
    if(image.src == preselected) {
        image.src = selected;
    } else {
        image.src = preselected;
    }
};
```

This work, but only when i give the img src an URL. I want to use: src = "selectedimg.png" and src = "preselectedimg.png", however when i do this it cant seem to find the image as no image is switched. Yes the images have those names in my wwwroot folder.

Comment: you images must be the same path with the file calling it if you want it like that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript dynamically change the location of image src - NO JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930079/javascript-dynamically-change-the-location-of-image-src-no-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this page is inside a folder on root, the path will be relative to the current directory *unless* you use

```
img.src = '/selectedimg.png'
```

for example...

You can also reset the base url of the current page by using the `<base>` html tag like so

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>This is an example for the <base> element</title>
        <base href="http://www.example.com/news/index.html">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Visit the <a href="archives.html">archives</a>.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

Also take a look at [Defining root of HTML in a folder within the site root folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371785/defining-root-of-html-in-a-folder-within-the-site-root-folder)

Comment: Turns out what i needed was for it to: ' show my full page url/ + selectedimg.png '

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have two images.

```
<img src="image1.jpg" id="img1" />
<img src="image2.jpg" id="img2" />
```

You want to click on img2 and change img1, from what I understand. So what you need is this little addition in img2 tag:

```
<img src="image2.jpg" id="img2" 
 onclick="document.getElementById('img1').src = 'image3.jpg'" />
```

That's it. I hope it is helpful :)